# How do I pass id but don't display it in URL

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have passed title of the post in act parameter like this:

```
$act = explode(' ', strtolower($post['title']));
$act = implode('-', $act);
```

I have included the following code in .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([a-z-]+) test.php?id=$1&act=$2
```

and my current friendly URL looks like this: http://demo.web/1/hello-world 
However, I want it to look like this: http://demo.web/hello-world 
but I also want to pass id as I am fetching data from ID itself. Writing query directly by post title may not be suitable in future as one post title may match to another. How can I pass ID but not show in the URL?

Comment: If you want to pass the `id` parameter from your old URI to the new one then it must be present there in your old URI.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions I can think of...

The first would be to create a unique URL, based on the title, when the page is saved.

If you save a page with the title "Hello World", then the URL path could be...

/hello-world

This path is saved along with the rest of the page content fields.

If another page is later created with the same title, then its URL might become ...

/hello-world-2

... and so on.

The second option, is to include the ID in the URL path, but not in it's RAW integer form. You could use some kind of hashing or encryption so you're not directly exposing database ID's.

A very simple implementation might be to just add some constant to the ID, and then hex encode it.

A slightly more sophisticated way might be to hex encode the ID and combine it with a hash of the ID + some secret key.

It will still be fairly trivial to figure out the numeric ID from a given URL path, but it would be extremely difficult for a hacker to create a valid page URL, just based on an ID.

If, for example, I wanted to extract all of the page content from a site. If the site uses raw ID's in the URL, I can simply iterate through some range of guessed ID numbers, generate each URL, and download the page.

If, however, the URL's contain a hash of the ID + secret key, I cannot generate a valid URL, without also knowing the secret key used for the hash.

Comment: I am not concerned about displaying raw id's, I just simply want the URL to look pretty. I want to do it from .htaccess if possible.

Comment: @AlishaLamichhane I've updated my answer to include another option. You could allow duplicate titles, but make URL unique.

Comment: @AlishaLamichhane One thing to consider, if saving the URL as an attribute of the page, is what to do when the title is changed. If you change the URL automatically, then you'll probably want to keep track of old URL's to ensure they are 301 redirected.

Comment: So how can I encrypt ID?